# Convert Date/Time for given Timezone - java

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, timezone, timestamp

I want to convert this GMT time stamp to GMT+13:

```
2011-10-06 03:35:05
```

I have tried about 100 different combinations of DateFormat, TimeZone, Date, GregorianCalendar etc. to try to do this VERY basic task.

This code does what I want for the CURRENT TIME:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");    
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+13"));  

String newZealandTime = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

But what I want is to set the time rather than using the current time.

I found that anytime I try to set the time like this:

```
calendar.setTime(new Date(1317816735000L));
```

the local machine's TimeZone is used. Why is that? I know that when "new Date()" returns UTC+0 time so why when you set the Time in milliseconds does it no longer assume the time is in UTC?

Is it possible to:

1. Set the time on an object (Calendar/Date/TimeStamp)
2. (Possibly) Set the TimeZone of the initial time stamp (calendar.setTimeZone(...))
3. Format the time stamp with a new TimeZone (formatter.setTimeZone(...)))
4. Return a string with new time zone time. (formatter.format(calendar.getTime()))

Comment: Too many questions in one post...

Comment: Same 2 questions asked just the 2nd one is asked a second time with a scenario algorithm for clarity. Thanks for input tho :?

Comment: Seems like the only problem is that `1317816735000L` is the wrong timestamp for `2011-10-06 03:35:05 GMT`.  Otherwise your approach is correct.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**For me, the simplest way to do that is:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

//Here you say to java the initial timezone. This is the secret
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
//Will print in UTC
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));    

//Here you set to your timezone
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
//Will print on your default Timezone
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: @Charleston What is the `review` in line `date = sdf.parse(review);`

Comment: @Charleston But there is no such method type in SDF, `sdf.parse(DateObject)` is not defined in java i am using `JDK.1.7`.

Comment: I feel so sorry about my second answer. I don't even tested it! But now Its tested and working!

Comment: How do you get an actual Date instead of a String?

Comment: Maybe it should be: SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

Comment: what are the values allowed for timezone(here we have UTC), is there any list of codes allowed ? @Charleston

Comment: I think you sould use TimeZone.getAvailableIds() method, but i didn't test.

Answer (score 31):

Understanding how computer time works is very important. With that said I agree that if an API is created to help you process computer time like real time then it should work in such a way that allows you to treat it like real time. For the most part this is the case but there are some major oversights which do need attention.

Anyway I digress!! If you have your UTC offset (better to work in UTC than GMT offsets) you can calculate the time in milliseconds and add that to your timestamp. Note that an SQL Timestamp may vary from a Java timestamp as the way the elapse from the epoch is calculated is not always the same - dependant on database technologies and also operating systems.

I would advise you to use System.currentTimeMillis() as your time stamps as these can be processed more consistently in java without worrying about converting SQL Timestamps to java Date objects etc.

To calculate your offset you can try something like this:

```
Long gmtTime =1317951113613L; // 2.32pm NZDT
Long timezoneAlteredTime = 0L;

if (offset != 0L) {
    int multiplier = (offset*60)*(60*1000);
    timezoneAlteredTime = gmtTime + multiplier;
} else {
    timezoneAlteredTime = gmtTime;
}

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timezoneAlteredTime);

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

formatter.setCalendar(calendar);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

String newZealandTime = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: @user726478  Is this correct when we know timezone string?          long timezoneAlteredTime = gmtTime + TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta").getRawOffset();"

Comment: Not good. Time zone offset is not constant. It depends on actual date.

Comment: How do you get an actual Date instead of a String?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar here offset is hours

Answer (score 28):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_317_816_735_000L )
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
    .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( new Locale( "en" , "NZ" ) ) )
```

…also…

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2011-10-06 03:35:05".replace( " " , "T" ) )
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
```

## java.time

The Question and most Answers use outdated legacy date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java. These old classes have proven to be troublesome and confusing. Avoid them. Instead use the java.time classes.

## ISO 8601

Your input string is nearly in standard ISO 8601 format. Just replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2011-10-06 03:35:05".replace( " " , "T" );
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Now parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) because the input lacks any information about offset-from-UTC or time zone. A `LocalDateTime` has no concept of offset nor time zone, so it does *not* represent an actual moment on the timeline.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

## `ZoneOffset`

You seem to be saying that from the business context you know the intention of this string is to represent a moment that is 13 hours ahead of UTC. So we instantiate a [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 13 ); // 13 hours ahead of UTC, in the far east of the globe.
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

Apply it to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. This becomes an actual moment on the timeline.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( offset);
```

## `ZoneId`

But then you mention New Zealand. So you had a specific time zone in mind. A time zone is an offset-from-UTC *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). So we can specify a `ZoneId` to a `ZonedDateTime` rather than a mere offset.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). For example, `Pacific/Auckland`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Apply the `ZoneId`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

You can easily adjust into another zone for the very same moment on the timeline.

```
ZoneId zParis = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdtParis = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zParis );  // Same moment in time, but seen through lens of Paris wall-clock time.
```

## Count from epoch

I strongly recommend against handling date-time values as a count from epoch, such as milliseconds from the start of 1970 UTC. But if you must, create a `Instant` from such a number.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_317_816_735_000L );
```

Then assign a time zone as seen above, if desired, to move away from UTC.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Your value of `1_317_816_735_000L` is:

- `2011-10-05T12:12:15Z` (Wed, 05 Oct 2011 12:12:15 GMT)
- `2011-10-06T01:12:15+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]` (Thursday October 06, 2011 01:12:15 in Auckland New Zealand).

## Generate strings

To generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, simply call `toString`. Note that `ZonedDateTime` wisely extends the standard format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString();
```

For other formats, search Stack Overflow for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Already covered many times.

Specify a [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) and a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
Locale l = new Locale( "en" , "NZ" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

Note that time zone has *nothing* to do with locale. You can have a `Europe/Paris` date-time displayed in Japanese language & cultural norms, or a `Asia/Kolkata` date-time displayed in Portuguese language and Brazil cultural norms.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 26):

As always, I recommend reading [this article](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php) about date and time in Java so that you understand it.

The basic idea is that 'under the hood' everything is done in UTC milliseconds since the epoch. This means it is easiest if you operate without using time zones at all, with the exception of String formatting for the user.

Therefore I would skip most of the steps you have suggested.

1. Set the time on an object (Date, Calendar etc).
2. Set the time zone on a formatter object.
3. Return a String from the formatter.

Alternatively, you can use [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). I have heard it is a much more intuitive datetime API.

Comment: Hi Bringer128 thanks for your reply it just seems ridiculous to me that there is no straight forward way to adjust a timestamp for a given timezone. Why include the functionality if all it does is alters the timezone tag in the formatted string... I will try Joda time. Thanks

Comment: @travega There is a simple way, if you represent your time as UTC and format it with a SimpleDateFormat. It is not just the 'Z' part (the timezone tag) that gets modified, the whole date does. Check the results of having two different SimpleDateFormat objects with different TimeZones set when they format the same date.

Comment: How do you get an actual Date instead of a String?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I think you will need to explain in more detail. Can you create a question or search to find a related question that might solve your specific question?

Answer (score 13):

The solution is actually quite simple (pure, simple Java):

```
System.out.println(" NZ Local Time: 2011-10-06 03:35:05");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime localNZ = LocalDateTime.parse("2011-10-06 03:35:05",formatter);
ZonedDateTime zonedNZ = ZonedDateTime.of(localNZ,ZoneId.of("+13:00"));
LocalDateTime localUTC = zonedNZ.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println("UTC Local Time: "+localUTC.format(formatter));
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
 NZ Local Time: 2011-10-06 03:35:05
UTC Local Time: 2011-10-05 14:35:05
```

Comment: This was solved 4 years ago and your solution does not add anything new.

Comment: I think that this is new approach using Java 8, but answer quality in low.

Answer (score 5):

Had a look about and I don't think theres a timezone in Java that is GMT + 13. So I think you have to use:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//OR Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+13);

Date d = calendar.getTime();
```

(If there is then change "GMT" to that Timezone and remove the 2nd line of code)

OR

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+13"));
System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
```

If you want to set a specific time/date you can also use:

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 15);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13); 
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
```

Comment: Hey Craig thanks for your reply. Java does not support/unsupported ISO time standards GMT is a global time standard moderated independent of java. The time/calendar Apis do adhere to the standard and GMT+13 refers to NZDT or daylight savings time in any GMT+12 zone. Regarding your sample code I have your scenario working without any issue, as mentioned in my IP. The problem I am facing is for defining a time stamp and outputting accurate timezone specific variants of the original time stamp, NOT derivations of the current time which is what your code does. Thanks T

Answer (score 3):

I have try this code

```
try{
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
            Date datetime = new Date();

            System.out.println("date "+sdf.format(datetime));

            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

            System.out.println("GMT "+ sdf.format(datetime));

            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+13"));

            System.out.println("GMT+13 "+ sdf.format(datetime));

            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            System.out.println("utc "+sdf.format(datetime));

            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");    
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+13"));  

            String newZealandTime = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

            System.out.println("using calendar "+newZealandTime);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and getting this result

```
date 06-10-2011 10:40:05 +0530
GMT 06-10-2011 05:10:05 +0000 // here getting 5:10:05
GMT+13 06-10-2011 06:10:05 +1300 // here getting 6:10:05
utc 06-10-2011 05:10:05 +0000
using calendar 06 Oct 2011 18:10:05 GMT+13:00
```

Comment: Hi pratik thanks for you input but you are missing the point. As mentioned in my IP I have it working for a current time stamp. The issue is with setting a time stamp and then generating accurate timezone specific output.

Comment: yeah it also work if you change the time. The time zone was set into the format object so whatever time you passed that will based on timezone which was specified into the format object

Comment: Hmmmm... I have tried adding: datetime.setTime(Timestamp.valueOf("2011-10-06 03:35:05").getTime()); And still it doesn't work. How do you figure it works when you set the time?

Comment: @Pratik: How Can I get AST time zone.

Answer (score 3):

We can handle this by using offset value

```
 public static long convertDateTimeZone(long lngDate, String fromTimeZone,
        String toTimeZone){
    TimeZone toTZ = TimeZone.getTimeZone(toTimeZone);
    Calendar toCal = Calendar.getInstance(toTZ);        

    TimeZone fromTZ = TimeZone.getTimeZone(fromTimeZone);
    Calendar fromCal = Calendar.getInstance(fromTZ);
    fromCal.setTimeInMillis(lngDate);
    toCal.setTimeInMillis(fromCal.getTimeInMillis()
            + toTZ.getOffset(fromCal.getTimeInMillis())
            - TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(fromCal.getTimeInMillis()));      
    return toCal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Test Code snippet:

```
 System.out.println(new Date().getTime())
 System.out.println(convertDateTimeZone(new Date().getTime(), TimeZone
                .getDefault().getID(), "EST"));
```

Output:
    1387353270742
    1387335270742

Answer (score 2):

I should like to provide the modern answer.

You shouldn’t really want to convert a date and time from a string at one GMT offset to a string at a different GMT offset and with in a different format. Rather in your program keep an instant (a point in time) as a proper date-time object. Only when you need to give string output, format your object into the desired string.

### java.time

**Parsing input**

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter();

    String dateTimeString = "2011-10-06 03:35:05";
    Instant instant = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant();
```

For most purposes `Instant` is a good choice for storing a point in time. If you needed to make it explicit that the date and time came from GMT, use an `OffsetDateTime` instead.

**Converting, formatting and printing output**

```
    ZoneId desiredZone = ZoneId.of("Pacific/Auckland");
    Locale desiredeLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-NZ");
    DateTimeFormatter desiredFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss OOOO", desiredeLocale);

    ZonedDateTime desiredDateTime = instant.atZone(desiredZone);
    String result = desiredDateTime.format(desiredFormatter);
    System.out.println(result);
```

This printed:

> 06 Oct 2011 16:35:05 GMT+13:00

I specified time zone Pacific/Auckland rather than the offset you mentioned, +13:00. I understood that you wanted New Zealand time, and Pacific/Auckland better tells the reader this. The time zone also takes summer time (DST) into account so you don’t need to take this into account in your own code (for most purposes).

Since `Oct` is in English, it’s a good idea to give the formatter an explicit locale. `GMT` might be localized too, but I think that it just prints `GMT` in all locales.

`OOOO` in the format patterns string is one way of printing the offset, which may be a better idea than printing the time zone abbreviation you would get from `z` since time zone abbreviations are often ambiguous. If you want `NZDT` (for New Zealand Daylight Time), just put `z` there instead.

**Your questions**

I will answer your numbered questions in relation to the modern classes in java.time.

> Is possible to:
>
> 1. Set the time on an object

No, the modern classes are immutable. You need to create an object that has the desired date and time from the outset (this has a number of advantages including thread safety).

> 2. (Possibly) Set the TimeZone of the initial time stamp

The `atZone` method that I use in the code returns a `ZonedDateTime` with the specified time zone. Other date-time classes have a similar method, sometimes called `atZoneSameInstant` or other names.

> 3. Format the time stamp with a new TimeZone

With java.time converting to a new time zone and formatting are two distinct steps as shown.

> 4. Return a string with new time zone time.

Yes, convert to the desired time zone as shown and format as shown.

> I found that anytime I try to set the time like this:
>
> ```
> calendar.setTime(new Date(1317816735000L));
> ```
>
> the local machine's TimeZone is used. Why is that?

It’s not the way you think, which goes nicely to show just a couple of the (many) design problems with the old classes.

- A `Date` hasn’t got a time zone. Only when you print it, its `toString` method grabs your local time zone and uses it for rendering the string. This is true for `new Date()` too. This behaviour has confused many, many programmers over the last 25 years.
- A `Calender` *has* got a time zone. It doesn’t change when you do `calendar.setTime(new Date(1317816735000L));`.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 2):

display date and time for all timezones

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;



static final String ISO8601 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO8601);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String formattedTime;
for (String availableID : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(availableID));
    formattedTime = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println(formattedTime + " " + availableID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

The java.util.Date/Calendar classes are a mess and should be avoided.

Update: The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

Here's your answer using the Joda-Time 2.3 library. Very easy.

As noted in the example code, I suggest you use named time zones wherever possible so that your programming can handle [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST) and other anomalies.

If you had placed a `T` in the middle of your string instead of a space, you could skip the first two lines of code, dealing with a formatter to parse the string. The [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor can take a string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

// Parse string as a date-time in UTC (no time zone offset).
DateTimeFormatter formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss" );
DateTime dateTimeInUTC = formatter.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( "2011-10-06 03:35:05" );

// Adjust for 13 hour offset from UTC/GMT.
DateTimeZone offsetThirteen = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours( 13 );
DateTime thirteenDateTime = dateTimeInUTC.toDateTime( offsetThirteen );

// Hard-coded offsets should be avoided. Better to use a desired time zone for handling Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies.
// Time Zone list… http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
DateTimeZone timeZoneTongatapu = DateTimeZone.forID( "Pacific/Tongatapu" );
DateTime tongatapuDateTime = dateTimeInUTC.toDateTime( timeZoneTongatapu );
```

Dump those values…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeInUTC: " + dateTimeInUTC );
System.out.println( "thirteenDateTime: " + thirteenDateTime );
System.out.println( "tongatapuDateTime: " + tongatapuDateTime );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeInUTC: 2011-10-06T03:35:05.000Z
thirteenDateTime: 2011-10-06T16:35:05.000+13:00
tongatapuDateTime: 2011-10-06T16:35:05.000+13:00
```

Answer (score 1):

**A quick way is :**

```
String dateText ="Thu, 02 Jul 2015 21:51:46";
long hours = -5; // time difference between places

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss, Locale.ENGLISH);     
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateText, formatter);        
date = date.with(date.plusHours(hours));

System.out.println("NEW DATE: "+date);
```

Output

**NEW DATE: 2015-07-02T16:51:46**

Answer (score 1):

Your approach works without any modification.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
// Timestamp for 2011-10-06 03:35:05 GMT
calendar.setTime(new Date(1317872105000L));

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); 
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+13"));

// Prints 2011-10-06 16:35:05 GMT+13:00
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Timestamp convertLocalTimeToServerDatetime(String dt,String timezone){

    String clientDnT = dt ;// "2017-06-01 07:20:00";
    try{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = sdf.parse(clientDnT);
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone.trim()); // get time zone of user
    sdf.setTimeZone(tz);

    // Convert to servertime zone 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    TimeZone tzInAmerica = TimeZone.getDefault();
    sdf1.setTimeZone(tzInAmerica);

    // assign date to date
    String serverDate = sdf1.format(date);

    // Convert to servertime zone to Timestamp
    Date date2 =  sdf.parse(serverDate);
    Timestamp tsm = new Timestamp(date2.getTime());
    return  tsm;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: please pass **date** and **client timezone**  ,then method returns server Timestamp .. **for javascript**  `var _timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;` and **in java** `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); tz.getID()`

Answer (score 1):

To find duration or time interval with two different time zone

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Period, PeriodType}

val s1 = "2019-06-13T05:50:00-07:00"
val s2 = "2019-10-09T11:30:00+09:00"    

val period = new Period(DateTime.parse(s1), DateTime.parse(s2), PeriodType dayTime())

period.getDays
period.getMinutes
period.getHours
```

output
    period = P117DT13H40M

```
days = 117
minutes = 40
hours = 13
```