# security.AccessControlException Error

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jetty, quartz-scheduler

When i used quartz trigger in backend java i am getting this error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:382)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:572)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:55)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:136)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:532)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.<init>(SimpleThreadPool.java:510)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.<init>(SimpleThreadPool.java:498)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.createWorkerThreads(SimpleThreadPool.java:288)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.initialize(SimpleThreadPool.java:277)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1273)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1502)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1518)
    at com.tiyaFdManager.backend.SimpleTrigger.SimpleTriggerNotification(SimpleTrigger.java:31)
    at com.tiyaFdManager.backend.RegisterUserDetails.RegisterUserDetails(RegisterUserDetails.java:70)
    at org.apache.jsp.mainpage_jsp._jspService(mainpage_jsp.java:82)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16:24:13.781
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:382)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:572)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:55)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:136)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:532)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.<init>(SimpleThreadPool.java:510)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.<init>(SimpleThreadPool.java:498)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.createWorkerThreads(SimpleThreadPool.java:288)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.initialize(SimpleThreadPool.java:277)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1273)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1502)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1518)
    at com.tiyaFdManager.backend.SimpleTrigger.SimpleTriggerNotification(SimpleTrigger.java:31)
    at com.tiyaFdManager.backend.RegisterUserDetails.RegisterUserDetails(RegisterUserDetails.java:70)
    at org.apache.jsp.mainpage_jsp._jspService(mainpage_jsp.java:82)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help me???

My code:

```
package com.tiyaFdManager.backend;

import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder; import org.quartz.CronTrigger; import org.quartz.JobDetail; import org.quartz.Scheduler; import org.quartz.SchedulerException; import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

import java.text.ParseException; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.Date; import java.util.logging.Level; import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob; import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;


/**  * Created by Coko Tiya on 4/20/2016.  */ public class SimpleTrigger {
    Date startDate, endDate;
    Logger log;
    public void SimpleTriggerNotification(String startDateStr, String endDateStr){
        Scheduler scheduler = null;
        log = Logger.getLogger(RegisterUserDetails.class.getName());
        log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        try {
            scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();


        JobDetail job = newJob(pushNotificationJob.class)
                .withIdentity("cronJob", "testJob")
                .build();

        String startDateStr1 = "20/04/2016 16:00:00.0";
        String endDateStr1 = "20/04/2016 17:00:00.0";


        try {
            startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.S").parse(startDateStr1);
            endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.S").parse(endDateStr1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        CronTrigger cronTrigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger1", "testJob")
                .startAt(startDate)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 12 19 1/3 ? * ").withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                .endAt(endDate)
                .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, cronTrigger);
        scheduler.start();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.info("getMessage" + e.getMessage());

        }

    } }
```

and i am calling this as:

```
 SimpleTrigger mSimpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger();
 mSimpleTrigger.SimpleTriggerNotification(dat,matdate);
```

please help i am stuck. I didn't understand the issue..what is this servelet issue??

Comment: If you are using Marshmallow then you need to add Runtime permission  to access the permission

Comment: how to do that ?? Its backend..i am not able to deploy it??

Answer (score 0):

Appengine had first class support for [cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron), which runs in a distributed context. You should use that.

The reason this fails is that appengine  has a whitelist of Java classes your app can access, and creating a thread (using the API Quartz is using) is not permitted.

A timed job running on a background thread won't work in this environment, instances can come up and down as they please, and importantly you can't know how many nodes are running at any point in time.