# How to create date with time as zero with specific timezone?

Tags: java

Assume the date is April 26, 2013. I need to create a date with time as zero with specific timezone.

Basically need to do a conversion of default time of one timezone to another

Ex: April 26,2013 need to be set with 00:00 with EDT or EST timezone
    then i need to find the equivalent time value for IST or any timezone.

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.APRIL, 26);
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to convert a `DateTime` from one timezone to another ?

If so you are going to want to use a `DateFormat`. More info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java)