# Convert Joda-Time to Timestamp in UTC zone

Tags: java, timezone, timestamp, jodatime, utc

The following segment of code formats and converts a date to the UTC zone using the Joda-Time API.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter=DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
DateTime dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime("15-Oct-2013 11:34:26 AM").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);        
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

It displays the following date exactly as expected.

```
2013-10-15T06:04:26.000Z
```

---

But when this date is converted to `java.sql.Timestamp` like so,

```
System.out.println(new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis()));
```

it displays the following date.

```
2013-10-15 11:34:26.0
```

This means the same date/time as given. The time zone UTC appeared to be ignored.

---

How to get `Timestamp` to correctly convert a date to UTC?

Comment: It's not that `TimeStamp` is ignoring the time zone, I believe it's using the local time zone for its `toString` method - needs to be validated.  Remember, things like `TimeStamp` and `Date` aren't meant to be used for display the results, that's what formatters are for...

Comment: Is there a way to tell `Timestamp` to use the UTC zone? It is needed in a [converter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19371138/1391249). I initially believed that there was something wrong with this converter.

Comment: AFAIK `TimeStamp` is simply a container for the number of milliseconds since the epoch, it doesn't carry any time zone details with it per say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that the `println()` method implicitly uses the `Timestamp#toString()` method while displaying it on the console which in turn uses the current JVM timezone to display date-time (the JVM timezone is the system timezone by default which the operating system uses), the original intention of the question was to persist `new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis())` to MySQL database **with the UTC zone** which will not happen for the reasons mentioned in the following related answers.

- [Inserting date / time in a specific zone into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34729690/1391249)
- [How to store date-time in UTC into a database using EclipseLink and Joda-Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34711487/1391249)

Answer (score 1):

Java `Timestamp.toString()` outputs in UTC (although it doesn't say as much in the javadoc, the source uses no TimeZone info).  Since your original date/time is in UTC, you will see the exact same output.