# How to use JodaTime type converter for Eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, converters, jodatime

Actually I want to use Joda-Time to store dates in my database (Postgresql) like it's described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371138/how-to-insert-date-time-in-the-utc-zone-into-mysql-via-eclipselink-using-joda-ti/19541389#19541389) or [this one](http://jcodehelp.blogspot.de/2011/12/persist-joda-datetime-with-eclipselink.html). 
 I use JSF running on Glassfish (3.1.2.2). 
 My problem is, I don't know how to use the converter for EclipseLink. EclipseLink is already shipped and bundled in Glassfish. 
How can I access eclipseLink from my IDE (Netbeans)?
Any other suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Why would you use some EclipseLink specific "Converter" when JPA 2.1 has standardised "AttributeConverter"?

Comment: JPA 2.1 is part of EE 7 and therefore not fully integrated with EE 6 GF 3.1.2.2. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @codyLine: you asked two questions: about conversion (What is the reason you don't know how to use it? The linked blog clearly describes how to use EclipseLink converter I guess) and access to EclipseLink (Are you missing EclipseLink's dependencies? Is the converter class not recognized by IDE?)

Comment: @wypieprz: EclipseLink is shipped with Glassfish as a module. With other words, it lives as a bunch of jar files inside a directory of Glassfish. I have no access to it from my IDE.

Comment: According to [EE 6 GF 3.1.2.2 Release Notes](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/3.1.2.2/release-notes.pdf#page=10&zoom=auto,60,159) it supports JPA 2.0 and most likely EclipseLink 2.3.2. Are you using Maven in your NetBeans project? If yes, just add the dependency to make it accessible.

Comment: I'm not using Maven but I'll give it try. Thanks @wypieprz