# How to return modified timezone Date object in java.

Tags: java, date, calendar

How to return modified timezone `Date` object in java. 
`SimpleDateFormat` class only formats and prints the date(in `String`) but it never changes the actual `Date` object.

Comment: Could you provided what you tried with SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Be specific. What are you trying to do to the date-time value?

(b) Check out [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8.

You can add or subtract minutes, hours, days, and such.

You can set the time portion to the first moment of the day.

You can set a specific time.

You can adjust to any other time zone.

You can compare if one date-time is before or after another.

Comment: Joda-Time had wider functions to fulfil my requirements. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Calendar` class to handle localization.