# "Cant create directory" error when updating timezone data with tzupdater.jar

Tags: java, timezone

I want to update the timezone data in Java. As I understood it might be solved using `java -jar tzupdater.jar --update`. But I get the error:

```
Cant create directory {0}
```

Java version is:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java

Comment: @HimaghnaDasgupta - That post is unrelated.

Comment: In other words, just run *cmd.exe* as an [**Administrator**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and then user the `java -jar tzupdater.jar --update`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error will occur if you run `tzupdater.jar` with insufficient privileges to create or edit the timezone data in the directory containing your Java installation.

You probably need to be an administrator user if you are on Windows. See [this related bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6530997) (although they don't get your exact error).