# Convert GMT to BST Java

Tags: java, timezone

I have a date format `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` in `GMT` format. I want to convert the date from `GMT` format to `BST` time. What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Date/Time for given Timezone - java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java)

Comment: Just one comment. There is no GMT format. The format of the date and the timezone are two different shoes. I guess you want to know what local BST time your GMT time is, right?

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8, the easiest way is probably to:

- parse the date into a LocalDateTime
- use it to create a ZonedDateTime using GMT time zone
- change the time zone to BST
- get the LocalDateTime of that new date

Sample example:

```
String date = "2015/03/09 10:32:00";
LocalDateTime gmt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
ZonedDateTime instant = ZonedDateTime.of(gmt, ZoneId.of("GMT"));
LocalDateTime bst = instant.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(bst);
```

If you change the month to July, for example, you should see an offset of one hour as expected.

(I assumed that BST is British Summer Time - it could also be Bangladesh Standard Time: in general it is better to use the full name of the time zone to avoid ambiguities).