# Conversion of time from UTC to other timezone failing with Gson

Tags: java, json, datetime, timezone, gson

I have stored my timestamps as `Timestamp` in my MySQL database. I retrieve them on my server, which works with UTC, and then convert these objects to json with `Gson`. `Gson` uses the JVM's timezone so it uses UTC on the server, which is what I want.

On my client side, I am in another timezone ("Europe/Amsterdam"), so I try to display dates in that timezone. I am retrieving the json, and then convert it to a list of objects using `Gson`. The dates that I retrieve at my client are UTC, so that is all going well. The objects have a `Date` attribute to store the dates. The json looks like this (partly):

`{"id":2,"timestamp_start":"Jan 13, 2015 10:44:45 AM GMT",...}`

In the conversion I used the following `TypeAdapter`:

```
public class DateTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private final DateFormat dateFormat;

    public DateTypeAdapter() {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }

    @Override public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type type,
        JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    @Override public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
      try {
        return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Then, to show dates in e.g. Tableviews, I simply use this to convert from UTC:

```
public static String dateToLocalTimeString(Date date) {

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy 'om' HH:mm");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
    return formatter.format(date);

}
```

The problem is: it keeps showing the same date and time as is stored in the database, which is UTC. Even if I get rid of the `TypeAdapter`, it does.

What am I missing here?

After the conversion, I tested the `Date` by calling `toString()`, and it shows the same date and time but now "CEST" appended, which I do not understand. I should be +2, but it is just the same date and time...

**UPDATE 2:** I now tried the conversion like this (based on Java 8 Date API)

```
public static String dateToLocalTimeString(Date date) {

    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy 'om' HH:mm");
    String formattedDateTime = ldt.format(formatter);

    return formattedDateTime;
}
```

It stills shows the time 2 hours early. I have printed the epoch timestamp now, and it has just converted GMT -> CEST without converting the time. So I assume the above `TypeAdapter` is not working, so in my opinion it has something to do with `Gson`..

Comment: Would you be willing to hear a solution that uses [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), or do you want to keep responses to the base JDK?

Comment: Due to the complexity of the system, shared classes on server and client, I would like to stick with storing the timestamp as `java.util.Date`. But this has to do with showing the date, so if this is possible with joda-time, I am ok with that..

Comment: The problem is that the JDK, `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, etc. is really bad at stuff like this; that's why libraries like joda time exist. I use joda time as a dependency in everything I do.

Comment: Regardless, your problem is not gson, your problem is the JDK date libraries. In fact...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Date/Time for given Timezone - java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java)

Comment: see update 2 with my reasons for why I think it has something to do with `Gson`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen to create a `DateTypeAdapter`, which does not use a `SimpleDateFormat`, because it looks like it does some unexpected things (which I do not know how to solve). I now convert all dates to epoch at the server, and convert them back at the client. Very easy, and does not use any timezone.

```
public class DateTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    public DateTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override 
    public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(date.getTime());
    }

    @Override 
    public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
        return new Date(Long.parseLong(jsonElement.getAsString()));
    }
}
```

When I want to show dates at the client, I can just show it with a `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to have SimpleDateFormat as **MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z**

```
{"id":2,"timestamp_start":"Jan 13, 2015 10:44:45 AM GMT",...}
```

In the conversion I used the following TypeAdapter:

```
public class DateTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private final DateFormat dateFormat;

    public DateTypeAdapter() {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z", Locale.US);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }

    @Override public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type type,
        JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    @Override public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
      try {
        return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Unfortunately, it is still showing the wrong date.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to covert UTC (sourceTZ) to other timezone

```
public static String converDateTZ(String dateFormat, String dateString ,  String sourceTZ, String destiTZ) {

    DateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a z");
    sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(sourceTZ));
    Date date = null;
    String parsDate = null;
    if (dateString != null) {
        try {
            date = sourceFormat.parse(dateString);
            DateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            if (destiTZ != null) {
                dFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(destiTZ));
            }
            parsDate = dFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return "";
        }
        return parsDate;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
```

}