# Converting UTC timestamp to local date

Tags: java, datetime, utc

So I tried now for about hours to convert a Timestamp to a local date (CEST).

```
     Date date = new Date(stamp*1000);
     SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CEST"));
     String myDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

It's not working whatever I tried and looked up in Internet I always get back the UTC time......

for better understanding: stamp is a variable timestamp with type long which I will receive from a service

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java

Comment: I tried the advice with 11 upvotes as you might have seen, its not working

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date)

Comment: I'm not using Java 8, working on Java 6 EE

Comment: @Nali is that 6 the version of the Server ? notice that jre version is different than the Java EE version that comes with the application server(Glassfish,JBoss,etc)

Comment: so you might have java 8 with a server that supports Java EE 6 only :) and they will run together, there isn't any strong relation between Java EE version and jre(jdk) version

Comment: @Nali You should post example data and results so we can verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
String output = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( Instant.ofEpochSecond ( 1_468_015_200L ) , ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Paris" ) ).toString();
```

## Details

A few issues:

- You are not using [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

  - Proper names are in `continent/region` format.
  - The 3-4 letter abbreviations so commonly seen in the media such as `CEST` are *not* true time zones. **Avoid them.** They are neither standardized nor unique(!).
- You are using old outmoded date-time classes that are poorly designed and confusing. They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

If by `CEST` you meant 2 hours ahead of UTC in the summer, then let's take [`Europe/Paris`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) as an example time zone. Your Question lacks example data, so I'll make up this example.

Apparently your input is a count of whole seconds from the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC. That value can be used directly, no need to multiply.

The `ZoneId` class represents the time zone. An `Instant` is a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds. A `ZonedDateTime` is the `Instant` adjusted into the `ZoneId`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Paris" );
long input = 1_468_015_200L;   // Whole seconds since start of 1970.
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( input );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | instant: " + instant + " | zdt: " + zdt );
```

> input: 1468015200 | instant: 2016-07-08T22:00:00Z | zdt: 2016-07-09T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]

Comment: @Nali Do you mean the format of the String that represents the value of the date-time? Your Question says nothing about formatting. Anyways, search Stack Overflow for many examples of using `DateTimeFormatter` to generate Strings in any format. The formats shown here comply with the ISO 8601 standard. You can specify other formats or let java.time localize automatically to any `Locale`.

Comment: @BasilBourque As stated in the comments the OP doesn't use Java 8 yet. I don't know what are his constraints but I suppose he has to deal with it for the moment.

Comment: @C.Champagne Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project. Those names come from the JSR 310 that defines java.time.

Comment: @BasilBourque Nice! I didn't know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `TimeZone` id is likely to be incorrect (well, not recognized by Java). It seems that instead of throwing an exception the `TimeZone` is evaluated to *UTC* in that case.

Try this instead:

```
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("ECT"));
```

[Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html) is a page giving some information about Java's `TimeZone` and a list of timezone ids.

Comment: I tried everything it will just show me the UTC time nothing else

Comment: @Nali What do you mean exactly by everything? Have you tried the `continent/region`format? `simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Brussels"));`for example

Comment: @Nali What does `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` return? Anyway, you should use one of those values.

Comment: nevermind it works now, don't know why but it works :D thanks