# Converting UTC time to different time zone

Tags: java

I want to convert UTC time to my desiered time zone, Im trying with the following code

```
        //inputDate - Timestamp (2016-10-15 12:30:00)
        //toZoneId -  Australia/Sydney

        ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(inputDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        Timestamp convertedTime = Timestamp.valueOf(utcDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(toZoneId)).toLocalDateTime());
        return convertedTime;
```

I get same "2016-10-15 12:30:00" as output not the UTC equivalent date time. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Date/Time for given Timezone - java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java)

Comment: What is the value of `inputDate.toLocalDateTime()`?