# Format date by provided time zone in java

Tags: java, date, timezone, format

I need to format date time in java for provided time zone. E.g. mm/dd/yyyy for US and dd/mm/yyyy for DE. I have time zone and i can get zoneId, can someone help me. Many thanks.

Comment: Try googling your title.

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you don't provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) with the code you have tried!!...

Comment: Go look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java

Comment: look here too [Link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist

Comment: I think people here misunderstand the question. It's not about displaying the time in a given time zone. It's about changing the date format based on the custom in the country, deducing the country from the time zone.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(Locale.US)`. Similarly with `Locale.GERMANY` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modern Java date and time classes for everything that has got to do with dates or times.

```
    DateTimeFormatter usFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.US);
    System.out.println(date.format(usFormatter));
    DateTimeFormatter deFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
    System.out.println(date.format(deFormatter));
```

This will print something like

```
6/27/17
27.06.17
```

It’s not exactly the formats you asked for, but it’s the formats Java thinks are appropriate for those two locales. I’d try them, and if the users complaint, build my own `DateTimeFormatter` from a pattern string (like `MM/dd/uuuu`, for example).

I used a `LocalDate` for the `date` in the code, but the same code should work with a `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

If you meant to deduce the locale from the time zone in a `ZonedDateTime`, I don’t think you can do that reliably. There are often many countries in a time zone, each country having its own locale and its own way of formatting dates. Germany, for example, shares its time zone with Norway, Sweden, Denmark, Poland, France, Switzerland, Austria and Italy, Spain, Serbia and many others.

And if you meant to deduce it from the time zone in an oldfashioned `Date` object, you certainly cannot simply because a `Date` does not hold a time zone in it.

Comment: That's what I need, I have date in Long, after I set default time zone, I create new Date(Long ticks), but I need to format it for explicit country. Your answer is good for it if you have Locale, but I have only time zone.

Comment: You may be able to make some guesses. I figure people in the mentioned countries will be able to read a date formatted with Germany locale even though they may not all think of it as their own.

Comment: To convert a `long` containing milliseconds since the epoch to something that can be formatted using the above code, use `Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisSinceEpoch).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))` — please fill in your user’s time zone instead of Berlin time zone. This gives you a `ZonedDateTime`, and as I said in the answer, my code should work with it.

Comment: You may want to investigate a little further whether there may either be a way to obtain the user’s locale or a way to have the client format the date. See for example http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=12253.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at this one article. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DateDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

        Date date1 = new Date();
        System.out.println(date1);

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date2 = new Date();
        System.out.println(date2);

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        Date date3 = new Date();
        System.out.println(date3);

   }
}
```

Output:

```
Tue Jun 06 14:02:51 IST 2017
Tue Jun 06 08:32:51 UTC 2017
Tue Jun 06 03:32:51 EST 2017
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. It was about displaying in different formats based on the time zone. In some countries the date format is mm-dd-yyyy, in some countries it is dd/mm/yyyy, etc..