# What is the best way to localize datetime for different countries?

Tags: jquery, datetime, localization, datetimepicker, dateformatter

I have a scenario where I have to show datetime in dd/mm/yyyy format in client side application(includes datepicker).But the date will be saved in default mssql date format which is mm/dd/yy or yyyy-mm-dd.The problem is everywhere I  select date from datepicker I have to convert datetime in yyyy-mm-dd manually.My application supports different countries and datetime format will differ.I would be grateful if anyone suggests me a best possible generic solution.

Comment: Have you settled on a programming language yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date by provided time zone in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384625/format-date-by-provided-time-zone-in-java)

Comment: I am using jquery in asp.net.